# How do I create a function that simulate the click on Update button for all posts?

Tags: functions, featured-post, bulk-import

I made a child function.php with this code.
All new posts will automatically use the attachment id for the image I have uploaded to my Media Library.

```
function wpsites_auto_set_featured_image() {
  global $post;
  $featured_image_exists = has_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
  if (!$featured_image_exists)  {
    $attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );
    if ($attached_image) {
      foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
        set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment_id);
        wp_reset_query();                                
      }
    }
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'wpsites_auto_set_featured_image');
```

The only problem is that I have to open all posts and update them before the feature image appears.

How can I bulk update all the images to the feature image?
How do I create a function that simulates the click on Update button for all posts?

Is this posible with: `wp_update_post( $my_post );`

Where to put it?

Comment: It will help to format your code properly to make it easier for others to read. Click the help link under the Add Comment button to see a summary of the available formatting options. Generally, code is formatting using the backtick: `

Comment: Why not adding image directly into your post loop something like this ?

wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) , $image_size );

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am a real beginner. Where do I place this code?

Comment: Problem solved, answer found on this site: if you want to use the '$update' argument (that is the 3rd) of the 'save_post' hook you need to add 3 as $accepted_args param on add_action (see docs).

add_action('save_post', 'wpsites_auto_set_featured_image', 10, 3);


For which it is 10 I do not know yet.